# Use WOP to prove that for integers $a, m > 0$ there are integers $q, r \ge 0$, with $r \in \{0,1,2,\dots, m-1\}$ such that $a=qm+r$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I just don't know where to start,  I tried induction but that didn't work.  I wrote a and m are greater than 0 and and we can say a is congruent to r(modm) but im notsure if thats correct.  Any hints?

Comment: This question is very similar to the more recent one asked at [How to prove if x ∈ ℕ and y ∈ ℕ, then (x mod y) ∈ ℕ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103260/how-to-prove-if-x-%e2%88%88-%e2%84%95-and-y-%e2%88%88-%e2%84%95-then-x-mod-y-%e2%88%88-%e2%84%95).

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $m$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=\{a-mk \mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap\mathbb{N}$. $A$ is a non empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then contain a least element,  $r$ say. Since $r\in A$, there must be $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $a-mq=r$. We now prove that $r<|m|$.

Let us assume that $r\geq |m|$, then $0\leq r-|m|=a-m(q+\epsilon), \epsilon=\pm 1 \in A$, contradiction because $r$ is minimal. This prove existence of $(q,r)$