# How to prove if $x \in\mathbb N$ and $y \in\mathbb N$, then $(x\mod y) \in\mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question says it all. It is obviously true, but how do you prove it with actual mathematical symbols?

Comment: What is your definition of $\bmod ?\ \ $

Comment: Below I have already accepted the answer

Comment: Why the downvote? There is actually no more context to give, and based on the answer below, it is a one step proof, so I wouldn't have any attempts unless I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: @MathBob Wasn't me, but I suspect it's because the (not exactly standard) meaning of the terms used in your question aren't found in your question. They're not even found in the comments; they had to be speculated by the answerer.

Comment: This question is very similar to the recent one asked at [Use WOP to prove that for integers $a, m > 0$ there are integers $q, r \ge 0$, with $r \in \{0,1,2,\dots, m-1\}$ such that $a=qm+r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103149/use-wop-to-prove-that-for-integers-a-m-0-there-are-integers-q-r-ge-0-w/3103278).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is your definition of operation 'mod'
$$ x\text{ mod }y = \min\{ x-k\cdot y : k\in \mathbb{Z}\,\land\, x-k\cdot y\geq0\} $$
Directly from definition, $x\text{ mod }y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ = \mathbb{N}$.

Note that the minimum of that set exists, because for example
$$ x\in \{ x-k\cdot y : k\in \mathbb{Z}\,\land\, x-k\cdot y\geq0\}$$
and natural numbers are a well-ordered set (every non-empty subset of them has a minimum).

Comment: One may want to use well-ordering to show that there is a min to that set ... if one wanted to be pedantic, which perhaps the OP wants to be.

Comment: @kcrisman Ok, I've edited my answer a little for this purpose

Comment: I have accepted your answer at least I tried. It says I can up vote in four minutes:)

Comment: UPDATE: Ok I have it let me